# Outlook 2010 won't allow IMAP folders to be searched

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, imap, microsoft-office-2010

In Outlook 2010 on a computer running Windows 7 Professional, I can search for email messages in non-IMAP folders, but not those in my two IMAP folders (SENT and INBOX). However, this feature on Outllook 2010 works fine on my older laptop running Vista. I have tried reindexing a few times and it didn't help.

Any ideas how to get the search function working on my IMAP folders?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is an indexing issue - because you're using IMAP you should have an OST file (which is offline). It is possible it's not being indexed. To see:

- On the Tools menu, point to Instant Search, and then click Search Options (Alternatively, click the arrow in the Instant Search pane, and then click Search Options on the menu).
- Under Indexing, verify that the data files that you want to include in your search are selected in the Index messages in these data files list.

Also make sure indexing is complete (in the same location).

Comment: I also having similar problem. I selected the IMAP mailbox, when I start searching. The Outlook title will jump to default Data File (PST) to search for it. It ignore the IMAP data file. My PST is setup as my auto archive folder. It's end up only show the old email but not the latest email result. I already rebuild the index many times.